# “Flattening” overlapping paths in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, transparency, flatten

I have 2 black separated areas:
[image: what it looks like]
Actually the 2 black areas have a different shape and are separated by white line of constant stroke width (shown in red here):
[image: with separator shown]
When I put this fiuigure over a different background (not white, with text), the white line becomes visible:

[image: on different background]

PS a workaround was to retrace exported bitmap, with this result:

[image: retraced]

[image: over background]
I would like to convert these 3 paths to 2 black-filled areas of which boundaries are the same as visible boundaries on the first picture. In raster graphics, this would be called "flattening", I don't know the right word for vectors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Select your black objects.
2. *Path → Combine.*
3. Select your line.
4. *Path → Stroke to Path.*
5. Make sure that your path is above your black objects *(Object → Raise to Top).*
6. Select your path and your black objects.
7. *Path → Difference.*
8. If desired, *Path → Break Apart.*

Comment: Cool, I missed the "Stroke to Path" part when experimenting with this. Thanks!